# How hide PDOException with zend framework 2 on production environment?

Tags: pdo, exception, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

We use a zend framework 2 for a web application.

We though to have disabled error_reporting and display_errors in our production environment.

But if an SQL error occured (It should not in production but ... :-) ), the exception is still displayed:

```
PDOException
File:
[...]/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:165
Message:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation
```

The query use Doctrine\DBAL\Statement (Doctrine2).

We cannot find where to globally catch this exception.

Comment: Have you set the `view_manager` config key `display_exceptions` to `false` in your `config/autoload/global.php`?

Comment: I have searched for display_exceptions config. key in all modules and found one that was kept with true value.

Thank you AlexP, It works ! :)

Comment: AlexP could you please convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Thanks @Jodaille, I've added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the correct `view_manager` config settings.

```
// config/autoload/global.php
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(        
        'display_not_found_reason' => false,
        'display_exceptions'       => false,
    ),
);
```

Remember that this config is *merged*; if it's in your main `global.php` it will take preference over the `module.config.php`.

**How it works**

Every time ZF2 encounters and error (an exception) it will *always* catch the error. Instead of 'rethrowing' the exception information to the screen, the info is added to the MVC event and an 'error' event is triggered (either `dispatch.error` or `render.error` depending on where it is within the dispatch loop).

The `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager` attaches 'error listeners' to handle these occurrences - (normally to show the error template). If you're using the standard skeleton application, [the default error template will check the `display_exceptions` option](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml#L4) and only render the error if it's enabled.

Answer (score 1):

inside: Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection

search for line :

```
$this->resource = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$this->resource->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and change it into:

```
$this->resource = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$this->resource->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
```

I don't know if there is a way to override it globally without changing it in the library itself..

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it, inside index.php

```
try {
    include ROOT . '/init_autoloader.php';

    Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php')->run();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if (IS_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER)
        throw $e;
    else {
        echo('Error : ' . $e->getCode() . " " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```